# Send to Compressed Folder not working properly

Tags: windows, zip, explorer

I am having a particular issue with Send to Compressed Folder. 
What i do is:
Select folder - right click - send to...

Usually it created a zipped file at the bottom of the current with the same name as the folder i wanted to zip. Lately, however, the position of the zipped folder is not the last one in the folder and it automatically makes me rename it. 
I know it's a minor issue, but since i deal with lots of zipped folder at work it would be nice to go back as it was.

Thanks in advance!